# php fetch value on other page

Tags: php

I am having three images.

```
<a href="a.php" class="btn"><img src="http://localhost/aaa/wp-content/themes/aaa/img/bouquet/1.png"><span class="bqy_no">1</span></a>
<a href="a.php" class="btn"><img src="http://localhost/aaa/wp-content/themes/aaa/img/bouquet/2.png"><span class="bqy_no">2</span></a>
<a class="show_img3 btn" href="a.php"><img src="http://localhost/aaa/wp-content/themes/aaa/img/bouquet/2.png"><span class="bqy_no">BRAUCHE MEHR</span></a><div class="hide_img3"><a href=#>2</a><a href="#">3</a>`
```

I want that on click of 1st, i should be redirected to a page a.php and get the value i.e if clicked thrugh 1, then on a.php i should get 1 and if clicked throught 2, i should get 2 on a.php

Comment: I see a lot of comments like this; often times, people don't know where to begin so they ask first (and so they've tried nothing).  I don't see anything wrong with that.  It would be good if they did some googling first, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add `ID` as URL Query and you will be able to get them on net page with `$_GET['id']`

```
<a href="a.php?id=1" class="btn"><img src="http://localhost/aaa/wp-content/themes/aaa/img/bouquet/1.png"><span class="bqy_no">1</span></a>
<a href="a.php?id=2" class="btn"><img src="http://localhost/aaa/wp content/themes/aaa/img/bouquet/2.png"><span class="bqy_no">2</span></a>
<a class="show_img3 btn" href="a.php?id=3"><img src="http://localhost/aaa/wp-content/themes/aaa/img/bouquet/2.png"><span class="bqy_no">BRAUCHE MEHR</span></a><div class="hide_img3"><a href=#>2</a><a href="#">3</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use $_GET variables on your links like so:

```
<a href="a.php?value=1" class="btn"><img src="http://localhost/aaa/wp-content/themes/aaa/img/bouquet/1.png"><span class="bqy_no">1</span></a>
<a href="a.php?value=2" class="btn"><img src="http://localhost/aaa/wp-content/themes/aaa/img/bouquet/1.png"><span class="bqy_no">1</span></a>
```

Then, on your a.php page, you can GET the value like so:

```
<?php

echo $_GET['value'];

?>
```

**Note:  It is highly NOT recommended to use $_GET without securing the data.  Please read up on PHP input security.**

Answer (score 1):

Add ?value=1, ?value=2, ?value=3 to each link, then on a.php, use this:

```
<?php

echo $_GET['value'];
// 1, 2 or 3 depending on the image clicked
?>
```